# How to SELECT data from table only recorded the last three days

Tags: mysql, date, select, days

I recorded data in field 'date' by mysql NOW() function. I want to SELECT data which recorded the last three days(today, yesterday and the day before yesterday),but no idea to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM tlb_students WHERE date ...?... ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tlb_students 
WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: What is the different between using NOW() and CURDATE() Zane? Is it possible to get data recorded before the day before yesterday if I use this in the early morning?

Comment: @AJOP `NOW()` produces a timestamp in format '`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`', whereas `CURDATE()` produces a date in format '`YYYY-MM-DD`', so with `NOW()`, you get posts that are made within EXACTLY 3 days from the current time, because hours/minutes/seconds are taken into account. This is assuming your `date` field is of either `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` types.

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE date >= subdate(NOW(), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is:

```
SELECT * FROM tlb_students WHERE date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY)
```